# What Should Mail Custom DNS Records Be With Vercel

Tags: hosting, vercel

I'm struggling to understand how to set up my mail server to work on my NextJS blog hosted with Vercel - I am not receiving any e-mail (I can send successfully).

My set-up:

NextJS front-end hosted on Vercel.

WordPress blog hosted on examplehosting.

Domain name purchased from exampledomainco.

At the moment I have my DNS records (for mail) set up as custom DNS on exampledomainco as:

```
mail.example.co.uk A 3600 76.76.21.21
mail.example.co.uk MX 86400 example.co.uk.
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that I had the name and content of the MX record the wrong way around, and it should have been:

```
example.co.uk MX 86400 mail.example.co.uk.
```

And the A record should have been pointing to my host IP - not Vercels, which is 76.76.21.21

Thanks to ChatGPT for the assistance!